# How to convert automl model ( using autosklearn ) to pmml?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, pmml, auto-sklearn

I I have already completed learning using autosklearn.calssification.AutoSklearnClassifer().
I want to convert the trained model to PMML.
After changing the SimpleClassificationPipeline to the sklearn pipeline in the trained model, I used the sklearn2pmml library, but it did not work.
How can I convert a model trained through autosklearn into PMML?

[automl_model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4hcC.png)

[automl_model_to_pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Xxe.png)

[modle_to_pmml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ssAi.png)

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using the [SkLearn2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) package for Scikit-Learn to PMML conversion work.

AutoML uses custom transformer and estimator types in the fitted pipelines. The SkLearn2PMML package does not support them yet (for a list of supported types, see [here](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sklearn#supported-packages)), so it fails with an error.

In principle, AutoML support can be added to SkLearn2PMML, but it would require some development work. If you're interested in seeing that happen, please consider opening a proper feature request with the project.